# Is there any open source framework for implementing a partition/replica storage system?

Tags: bigdata, storage

I need to implement a distributed storage system for a real-time engine. Some of the basic requirements of the storage system are:

1) partition data to different partitions

2) each partition has replicas for fault-tolerance and data-persistence

3) dynamic scaling nodes

It seems like a common feature for a lot of big data projects. So I'm wondering is there any open-source framework that can make this easier? I did some digging but found nothing useful. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is obvious, but HDFS is what most big data projects use under the hood, and as part of Hadoop it's open source.

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html